# how to show google analytics graph using google visualization api

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-visualization

i am using Google analytics for my website and i want to show the number of visitors to my users.
I dont think google analytics provides any graph embed to use it in the website. 
So i decided to use data from google analytics and graph from visualization Api to accomplish this. I dont want to use any third party graph generating API(except Google), i am new to this and struck with how to proceed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var queryString = '';
  var dataUrl = '';

  function onLoadCallback() {
    if (dataUrl.length > 0) {
      var query = new google.visualization.Query(dataUrl);
      query.setQuery(queryString);
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    } else {
      var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dataTable.addRows(8);

      dataTable.addColumn('number');
      dataTable.setValue(0, 0, 37.704918032786885);
      dataTable.setValue(1, 0, 54.09836065573771);
      dataTable.setValue(2, 0, 55.73770491803279);
      dataTable.setValue(3, 0, 75.40983606557377);
      dataTable.setValue(4, 0, 52.459016393442624);
      dataTable.setValue(5, 0, 73.77049180327869);
      dataTable.setValue(6, 0, 68.85245901639344);
      dataTable.setValue(7, 0, 55.73770491803279);

      draw(dataTable);
    }
  }

  function draw(dataTable) {
    var vis = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    var options = {
      chxl: '',
      chxp: '',
      chxr: '0,0,46',
      chxs: '',
      chxtc: '',
      chxt: 'y',
      chs: '300x225',
      cht: 'lc',
      chco: '3D7930',
      chd: 's:Xhiugtqi',
      chdl: '',
      chg: '14.3,-1,1,1',
      chls: '2,4,0',
      chm: 'B,C5D4B5BB,0,0,0'
    };
    vis.draw(dataTable, options);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }
    draw(response.getDataTable());
  }

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["imagechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoadCallback);

</script>
```

Comment: I know you stated you didn't want to use a 3rd party tool.  But for those that might come across this thread and are not opposed to a 3rd party solution, check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com.  This is a "no programming required" service which accomplishes exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that should help. It was updated in Jan 2012 for Google’s API changes - [Introducing the Google Analytics Core Reporting API](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/12/introducing-google-analytics-core.html):

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/06/23/google-analytics-data-export-api-with-google-chart-visualizations-2/